# Is there a maximum size of a raster layer in PostGIS where regular blocking is supported?

Tags: postgis, raster

I'm using `raster2pgsql` to load a 5m DTM of England into Postgis. I'm trying to add the regular blocking constraint, but when I try this, it fails with the error:

`NOTICE:  Unable to create coverage raster. Cannot add coverage tile constraint: rt_raster_new: Dimensions requested exceed the maximum (65535 x 65535) permitted for a raster (XX000)`

Which is generated after loading SQL generated by: `raster2pgsql -s 27700 -t 50x50 -I -C -r -e -Y *.asc terrain` (I've also tried including `-P`, 256x256 tiles and no tiling).

Googling for this, the only reference to this error I can find is the relevant source SQL source and (if I understand it correctly) I *think* it's trying to make a single raster image out of the hulls of *all* the tiles in my DTM layer.

Have I understood this correctly, and does this mean that there is a maximum total size of 65535 x 65535 for a PostGIS raster layer if you want to use regular blocking?

Comment: As of regular blocking, there is more information here: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRaster/Documentation01